# How do I compare rates of error between two different sample sizes?

Tags: statistics, interpolation, sampling

I'm unsure on how to normalize for two different variables.

Person A makes 20 pastries total, whereas Person B makes 50.

5 of those pastries, so 25%, are sampled from Person A; 10 for Person B, for a sample of 20%.

The pastry chef determines from the samples that 2 of Person A's pastries are subpar, compared to 5 for Person B.

Therefore the chef interpolates that 50% of Person B's pastries are subpar to standards, compared to 40% for Person A. But that seems like shallow reasoning, since Person B's made at least twice more pastries than A.

Thus, how do I normalize to compare Person A and Person B taking into account sampling size and rate of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking to compare two rates.

The error rate of $A$ was measured to be $2$ out of $5$, i.e. $40\%$.

The error rate of $B$ was measured to be $5$ out of $10$, i.e. $50\%$.

That's it. Neither the sample size nor the total production size do influence these ratios and there is no need/possibility to normalize.

The only difference size can make is about the dispersion of the results (variance), which is larger for a smaller sample, i.e. giving a less accurate estimate of the mean.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why wouldn't it matter if the sampling for Person A was 25% compared to 20% for person B? Wouldn't Person A's rate of error be a more accurate measure than B's? This is just based on my intuition but it feels like I'm ignoring a variable.

Comment: @Hadrien: the sample size governs accuracy. But there is nothing else that you can compare than averages, which are unbiaised estimators. There is no way of improving the estimates, they are already optimal. The theory of estimation can tell yo how reliable (they say how significant) the comparison is. You are lumping together the expectation and the dispersion.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to $compare$ the performances of A and B.
Then you need to do a test of the null hypothesis $H_0: \pi_A = \pi_B$ against 
$H_a: \pi_A \ne \pi_B,$ where $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ are the
true error rates for A and B, respectively.

**Your small samples.** Two kinds of tests are in common use to judge whether
two such proportions differ. One assumes the the two
binomial proportions are nearly normally distributed.
That is not a safe assumption with so little data. Here
are results from Minitab.

```
  > PTwo 5 2 10 5.

  Test and CI for Two Proportions 

  Sample  X   N  Sample p
  1       2   5  0.400000
  2       5  10  0.500000

  Difference = p (1) - p (2)
  Estimate for difference:  -0.1
  95% CI for difference:  (-0.629553, 0.429553)
  Test for difference = 0 (vs not = 0):  
     Z = -0.37  P-Value = 0.711

  * NOTE * The normal approximation may be 
  inaccurate for small samples.
```

The second test is 'Fisher's Exact Test'. It is based on
the hypergeometric distribution. Minitab's procedure for
comparing proportions also does that test. Results are below:

```
 Fisher's exact test: P-Value = 1.00
```

So, apparently, you do not have enough data to say that A's 40%
error rate is meaningfully different from B's 50% error rate.

However, if you are interested more generally in methods to compare two
such proportions, please look in you statistics text for
details of these two tests.

**Hypothetical large samples.** In particular, suppose you have about 100 times as much data
for each individual, and with similar error rates. Then here are
results from Minitab:

```
 MTB > PTwo 500 201 1000 498.

 Test and CI for Two Proportions 

 Sample    X     N  Sample p
 1       201   500  0.402000
 2       498  1000  0.498000

 Difference = p (1) - p (2)
 Estimate for difference:  -0.096
 95% CI for difference:  (-0.148984, -0.0430161)
 Test for difference = 0 (vs not = 0):  
     Z = -3.55  P-Value = 0.000

 Fisher's exact test: P-Value = 0.000
```

With this increased amount of data, we would have plenty of evidence
to judge the two error rates different. It is not simply the size of
the difference that is persuasive, but the amount of evidence
to make sure the rates (still about 40% and 50%) are reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've researched Minitab a bit, would you recommend it as an intro to statistic for someone with limited/layman understanding of the discipline? Also in your second example, with the larger dataset, what is the estimated difference measuring exactly and how are you interpreting it?

Comment: For the test statistic and its interpretation, google 'test to compare two proportions' for explanations, explanation from STAT 414 at Penn State seems a good one. You can also google 'fisher exact test' (maybe Wikipedia). // Minitab is useful statistical software and can be helpful for beginners; a temporary license for a semester may be reasonably priced, but a permanent license for long term use may cost too much for an individual user. R is free, but maybe not so easy to start using on your own. Look at the R-tutorial from the search above to judge for yourself.

Comment: I'm currently using Minitab for work, so maybe I can convince my employers to invest in it. Although I thought they had rates for $30/month for individual users, which isn't the worst but isn't exactly cheap either... Anyhow I appreciate again your help, and I need to learn R sooner or later. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps more urgently, you should read up on the statistical theory behind these tests.